# Projection map for smooth vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm wondering why it is necessary, in the definition of a smooth vector bundle $\pi: E\rightarrow B$, to posit that $\pi$ be a smooth map, as opposed to just continuous.

If we know that $E$ and $B$ are smooth manifolds and $\pi$ is continuous, and we suppose that $B$ has a trivialising open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ (so that $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is open in $E$, hence a submanifold, so that we can talk about it being diffeomorphic to $U_\alpha\times\mathbb{R}^k$), then it follows that in the natural choice of local coordinates on $U_\alpha\times\mathbb{R}^k$ the map $\pi$ is just projection in Euclidean space, which is smooth.

Doesn't this mean that $\pi$ is necessarily smooth, provided it is continuous?

Comment: How do you know that $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is diffeomorphic to $U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k$, not just homeomorphic, which is one of the axioms that $\pi:E\to B$ is a continuous bundle? I mean, the smooth structure on $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ need not be the standard smooth structure on $U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^k$, isn't it?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is see if we can define smooth vector bundles (not continuous ones) with all other requirements being the same but weakening the assumption about smoothness of the projection. In the usual definition of smooth vector bundle, $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)$ is diffeomorphic to $U_\alpha\times\mathbb{R}^k$, so we keep this assumption.

Comment: If you mean you want to know what happened if one adds in the axiom of a continuous vector bundle that 1. the total and base space is smooth, 2. the local trivializion map is smooth, then you're right; the projection map is locally just the standard projection, thus smooth.